# How can I handle Geo Location popup in mozilla and chrome browser using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Please, see the following screenshot:

[image: screen shot for my question]

How can I handle Geo Location popup in mozilla and chrome browser using selenium webdriver?

```
    package tiyotesting;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    public class Citydropdownlist {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("http://www.google.com");
            driver.get("http://ec2-35-154-164-82.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/tiyorelease3/");
            WebElement ListBox = driver.findElement(By.id("supported_city_label"));
            ListBox.sendKeys("Ahmedabad");
            ListBox.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        }
    }
```

I created Firefox custom profile it is also not working again the popup came it is showstopper for me, so please help me to resolve the issue

Comment: I created Firefox custom profile it is also not working again the popup came  it is showstopper for me, so please help me to resolve the issue

Comment: Im unable to see the geolocation popup in google.com - it auto redirects for me. Please consider providing a screenshot for the popup.

Comment: where i have to attach the file

Comment: Please edit your question and attach the image within.

Comment: I edited and attached sir check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While working with Selenium 3.x, geckodriver v0.16.1 & Mozilla Firefox 53.x, you can disable the Geo Location popup by setting the preferences in the new Firefox profile as follows:

1. You have to download the geckodriver.exe from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). Save it on your machine.
2. You have to mention the absolute path of the geckodriver.exe through `System.setProperty`
3. You don't require to do `driver.get("http://www.google.com");` to open any other URL.
4. Here is the working set of minimal code which opens the intended URL without the Geo Location popup.

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");
   FirefoxProfile geoDisabled = new FirefoxProfile();
   geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.enabled", false);
   geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.provider.use_corelocation", false);
   geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing", false);
   geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing.allow", false);
   WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(geoDisabled); 
   driver.get("http://ec2-35-154-164-82.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/tiyorelease3/");
   ```

Comment: Sir I have one more problem with the same code... How I can select the item in the list box? please help me @DebanjanB

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Sir @DebanjanB

Answer (score 3):

The usage initialization of firefox Driver with a FirefoxProfile object has been deprecated. I've used that instead, adding the same preferences. And It worked for me

```
File gecko = new File("C:\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");

FirefoxOptions ffopt = new FirefoxOptions()
    .addPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false)
    .addPreference("geo.enabled", false)
    .addPreference("geo.provider.use_corelocation", false)
    .addPreference("geo.prompt.testing", false)
    .addPreference("geo.prompt.testing.allow", false);


System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", gecko.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffopt);
```