# How to enable or disable geolocation by selenium test case

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to allow/block my current location accessible to site by clicking on allow button of that popUp, my chrome version is **62.0**, chrome driver version is **3.6.0** and I am using ubuntu **16.04** and my code snippet is,

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--incognito");
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-geolocation");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,options);
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

But this is not working, could anyone suggest me the perfect solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I handle Geo Location popup in mozilla and chrome browser using selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321401/how-can-i-handle-geo-location-popup-in-mozilla-and-chrome-browser-using-selenium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Use `java.awt.Robot` class for this, first test manually and then you can change the key handlers as needed.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a way to do it without out robot, you can do it with options:
To deny set profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation to 1, to auto accept set to 2 (which seems to the current default)

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    
    ArrayList<String> opArgList = new ArrayList<>(); // using an array list (so we can extend it with other passed in options)
    opArgList.add("--no-sandbox");
    opArgList.add("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    String[] opArg = opArgList.toArray(new String[0]);
        
    HashMap<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation", 1); 
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    options.addArguments(opArg); 

    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/"), options);
```