# How to handle geolocation pop using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I handle the geolocation popup in Selenium WebDriver?

[image: Geolocation popup]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I handle Geo Location popup in mozilla and chrome browser using selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321401/how-can-i-handle-geo-location-popup-in-mozilla-and-chrome-browser-using-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have loaded the main page only do this:

```
WebElement elem = FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class,
                    NoSuchElementException.class)
            .until(ExpectedConditions
                    .elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='allow']")));
elem.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Launch Naukri.com then use below code:

```
    //For "Sure"
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("allow")));
    driver.findElement(By.id("allow")).click();
```